How do I display loading screen while EJS is rendering content
I'm making website using NodeJS, Express JS and EJS. In some pages, they need to execute lots of database queries and it should take long time. I want to display loading screen during this time, however, it even can't go to the website (browser shows it's connecting to website ig), so I can't do anything while EJS is rendering.
Sometimes, it took very long time to load the website, I don't know if there's anything error or not, so I want to make a loading screen. Please tell me if you need any code, thanks!
Edit: Someone may misunderstand what I meant, so let me explain how EJS works in my case. The NodeJS server will execute the queries to get data from database, which is impossible in pure HTML, JS. After that, the server will pass these data as parameters using below code
app.get("/page", (req, res) => {
  // get data...
  res.render("filename", data);
});

The server is already set up to render EJS file (the render file must end with .ejs). Inside EJS file, I will use these data, and EJS will convert the code like <%= data.id %>, <%= data.name %>... into real data that I've put as parameters and the file will become HTML file. After this, I think it will render the file like how Express JS normally does. So the progress of getting data, converting can take a while, after that will render HTML (converted EJS) file.

It would be nice if the question you asked was not "Is there any solutions for this?" (question lies in some other sentence, and it's way too general), and was not "how to display loading screen" (I assume it's not impossible to display a loading screen).  Where are you actually stuck?  I assume you're using ejs's async rendering features?

Thanks for you feedback. So I need to get data from database first in the server, then pass it to EJS and it will render the page. However, the time for getting data can take a while, leads to slow loading of the page. It's not render a blank page then appear content, the website even doesn't load.

You cant. Why? Because you send only a response to the client when node.js has done all queries. Thats what server side rendering with ejs does. You simple cant do what you want.

Ok, thanks for your help!

@Marc is 100% right on that. The only way I see it possible is like @ Bob says in his answer.

For a page that takes a long time to load, you can deliver a page that just shows your "Content Loading" messages, without running the long-running database queries. Since it's not running those queries and just delivering some HTML, it should display quickly. Within those pages you can embed a <script> that makes an AJAX call to a separate endpoint that will run the database queries and then return the data. Once the script receives the response it can dynamically update the page to show the content. For example:
<div id="content">Content loading</div>
<script>
  function renderContent(data){
    //...
  }
  let data = await fetch('/my/long/running/query/path')
  renderContent(data)
</script>


It's not render a blank page then appear content after getting data, the website even doesn't load (the browser shows the website is loading/connecting)

That's because you are running your queries before sending a fully populated HTML page to the client. I am suggesting that you rewrite it to just send a blank page, without running any queries. The blank page would include a script that would reach out to the server to get the actual data separately.

After a few hours of researching on the internet, I've found this solution.
// required libs
const path = require('path');
const ejs = require('ejs');

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  res.write("<h1>Loading...</h1>"); // replace html body of your loading screen here
  res.flushHeaders();
  // get data here, eg: let data = db.get({...});
  const EJSCONTENT = await ejs.renderFile(path.join(__dirname, "path/to/file.ejs"), data);
  res.write("<script>document.body.innerHTML = '';</script>"); // empty body (remove loading screen)
  res.write(EJSCONTENT); // render EJS file: get converted .ejs file to html and write it
});

This way may take you a while to re-setup your web app, but it works! 
Edit: Sorry, I didn't notice that I run the convert EJS file content before make the website empty. This is the new code and it should work. I know it's terrible and take lots of time, but I can't think any other ways for my problem.

That might be work, but is a terrible solution. The HTML is invalid, no doctype, no version, no headers, and then render/send the ejs template that possible sends all mentioned above. Thats not how you should do it. Either, create a API that can be fetched from the frontend with client side rendering, where you can implement a loading screen or stick with server side rendering and ejs. Mixing both where the backend is messing with the frontend is a terrible approach!

HTML, doctype, version, ... you can make a HTML file then code the loading screen and paste it here. Or use fs to read the HTML file content then write. The provided code above just an example. Anyways, thank for your comment that I realized the problem of my code!
